# Application instance in viewmodel is null

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use manual dependency injection and have a UserViewModel that gets the user repository from MyApplication.

This is my UserViewModel:

```
class PreferenceViewModel(
    private val prefRepo: PreferenceRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    // other functionalities

    companion object {
        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as MyApplication)
                UserViewModel(application.prefRepository)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is MyApplication code:

```
private const val USER_PREFERENCE_NAME = "user_preference"

private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(
    name = USER_PREFERENCE_NAME
)

class MyApplication: Application() {

    lateinit var prefRepository: PreferenceRepository

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        prefRepository = PreferenceRepository(dataStore)
    }

}
```

I have set the application name correctly in manifests as well. But I get this error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type MyApplication`

Update: this is how I get the viewModel in compose function:

```
@Composable
fun PreferencePage(
    navController: NavHostController,

    prefViewModel: PreferenceViewModel = viewModel(
        factory = PreferenceViewModel.Factory
    )
) {
    // implementation
}
```

**Update 2: my activity class code**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "PreferencePage") {
                        composable("PreferencePage") {
                            PreferencePage(navController = navController, viewModel)
                        }
                        // other codes
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get your ViewModel with your custom Factory: `private val viewModel: PreferenceViewModel by viewModels { PreferenceViewModel.Factory }`?

Comment: @TamHuynh yes I have done that but differently since I use it in composable view, I will update the question to make it clear

Comment: Why not inherit from [`AndroidViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel) if you want to access the `Application` instance?

Comment: @Michael how would that solve the issue? still have to provide the application instance for the constructor AndroidViewModel.
The issue is that the application instance is null in this line:

val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as MyApplication)

Comment: If you just want to pass the application to ViewModel, the default factory can provide it for you, use `viewModel()` Composable without any factory required. Then you can retrieve your repository inside `init` block. I still don't know why your Factory code doesn't work

Comment: Where do you use `PreferencePage`? Based on the `viewModel()` code and this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory. Only `Activity`, `Fragment`, and `NavBackStackEntry` are capable of having a default provider to give you the application when creating `ViewModel`

Comment: @TamHuynh updated my question, added activity where I show PreferencePage

Comment: Can you debug to see what is the value of `LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current` at the time you create the `PreferencePage`, to see if that object inherits from `HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory` or not?

Comment: @TamHuynh the PreferencePage is not created since the the error occurs in the viewmodel initialization. So I cannot do that.